# contract code size to big

Tags: solidity, contract-development, contract-design, bsc

Good day,

i have maded a smart contract
but it seems to be to big
i have maded some libaries such as context ownable safemath
but i still keep the same message

can someone mayby explain me how to shorter the code without affecting the functions, or help me to solve this
kind regrards, joel

[Link to the Contract](https://gist.github.com/joniksl/641989db4ce2bd4ddc7c817ec28d2894#file-contracts-ratcoin-sol)

[image: error message]

Comment: i have tryed with the optimise then i have indeed no errors but when i try to transact it says the gas estimation error

i am going to try to split the contract first time i am going to try it

Answer (score 2):

You can try to optimise contract size by getting rid of unnecessary imports or functions. Reducing the number of variables, function parameters are all valid attempts, but it'll all depend on the implementation details.

Alternatively, you cal also split it into multiple contracts. You can create a library contract with basic functions. And your main contract can call the library functions.